# AngularJS: Disable options in a selection list based on the value of another selection list

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I have 3 selection lists as '**Language**', '**News Provider**' & '**News Category**'.
I want to **enable/disable** options in '**News Provider**' & '**News Category**' based on the value of '**Language**'.
I have following code:

```js
$scope.languages = [
                      {"lang": "English"},
                      {"lang": "French"},
                      {"lang": "Portuguese"}
                    ];
$scope.providers = [
                      {"provider": "BBC"},
                      {"provider": "CNN"}
                    ];
$scope.categories = [
                       {"category": "General"},
                       {"category": "Sport"}
                    ];
$scope.formInfo.language     = $scope.languages[0];
$scope.formInfo.newsProvider = $scope.providers[0];
$scope.formInfo.newsCategory = $scope.categories[0];
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="language" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Language:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="language" class="form-control" id="language" ng-model='formInfo.language'  ng-options='language.lang for language in languages'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newsProvider" class="col-sm-2 control-label">News Provider:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="newsProvider" class="form-control" id="newsProvider" ng-model='formInfo.newsProvider'  ng-options='provider.provider for provider in providers'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newsCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">News Category:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="newsCategory" class="form-control" id="newsCategory" ng-model='formInfo.newsCategory'  ng-options='category.category for category in categories'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior? any help would be very kind

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code as follows and it works great now.

```js
$scope.languages = [
                      {"language": "English", "value": "English"},
                      {"language": "French", "value": "French"},
                      {"language": "Portuguese", "value": "por"}
                    ];
  $scope.providers = [
                      {"provider": "BBC", "lang": ["English", "French", "Portuguese"]},
                      {"provider": "CNN", "lang": ["English"]}
                    ];
  $scope.categories = [
                       {"category": "General", "lang": ["English", "French", "Portuguese"]},
                       {"category": "Sport", "lang": ["English"]}
                    ];
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="language" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Language:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="language" class="form-control" id="language" ng-model='formInfo.language'  ng-options='language.value as language.language for language in languages'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newsProvider" class="col-sm-2 control-label">News Provider:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="newsProvider" class="form-control" id="newsProvider" ng-model='formInfo.newsProvider'  ng-options='provider.provider for provider in providers | filter:{lang:formInfo.language}'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newsCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">News Category:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select name="newsCategory" class="form-control" id="newsCategory" ng-model='formInfo.newsCategory'  ng-options='category.category for category in categories | filter:{lang:formInfo.language}'></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```